# Why variable output here with channels

Tags: go, channel

I am trying code modified from [here](https://play.golang.org/p/OeYLKEz7qKi). I create 5 channels and send data 5 times:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func greet(c chan string) {
    fmt.Println("Hello " + <-c + "!")
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan string)
    for i:=0; i<5; i++ {
        go greet(c)
    }
    c <- "AAA"
    c <- "BBB"
    c <- "CCC"
    c <- "DDD"
    c <- "EEE"
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

I expected all 5 strings to be printed. However, I find variable output. Some outputs are:

```
$ ./rnchannel
main() started
Hello AAA!
Hello DDD!
Hello BBB!
Hello CCC!
Hello EEE!
main() stopped

$ ./rnchannel
main() started
Hello CCC!
Hello DDD!
main() stopped

$ ./rnchannel
main() started
Hello CCC!
Hello BBB!
Hello AAA!
Hello DDD!
main() stopped
```

Why variable number of lines are being printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@AdamSmith identified the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368727/14660). When `main()` exits all goroutines are killed. There's no guarantee your other goroutines will finish before that, that's the nature of concurrency. Here's how you fix it.

First, let's make a couple changes to `greet`. Have it sleep just a moment to make the problem more pronounced. We'll also have it accept a string rather than the channel, we'll see why in a moment.

```
func greet(str string) {
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Hello " + str + "!")
}
```

Rather than creating a bunch of goroutines to read a fixed number of times from a channel, we want one goroutine which reads from the channel until it's exhausted. This is easiest done using [`range`](https://gobyexample.com/range-over-channels). This takes full advantage of channels.

We also need a way to tell the main program to wait until the loop is done. [This is easiest done with a second channel](https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization). More complex synchronization uses [WaitGroups](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups).

```
c := make(chan string, 2)
done := make(chan bool, 1)
go func() {
    for str := range(c) {
        greet(str)
    }
    done <- true
}()
```

The goroutine will read from `c` until it's closed. Then it will send `true` to the channel `done`. Both are buffered to avoid deadlock due to blocking waiting to read or write to the channel.

Back in `main`, we write to the channel, explicitly close it, and then wait to read from `done`.

```
    c <- "AAA"
    c <- "BBB"
    c <- "CCC"
    c <- "DDD"
    c <- "EEE"
    close(c)

    <-done
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
```

`<-done` will block until there is something to read. This allows the goroutine to finish.

And bringing it all together.

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
func greet(str string) {
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Hello " + str + "!")
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan string, 2)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    go func() {
        for str := range(c) {
            greet(str)
        }
        done <- true
    }()
    c <- "AAA"
    c <- "BBB"
    c <- "CCC"
    c <- "DDD"
    c <- "EEE"
    close(c)

    <-done
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: Why it is ending before completion of all tasks. What is the advantage?

Comment: Why was Go designed like that? I'll guess to ensure Go programs reliably stop.

Comment: Does it ban a statement as:  'for {}' which will run forever?

Comment: @mso No. Loops are a lot simpler than concurrency.

Answer (score 3):

You're not waiting until all strings are printed to exit. As soon as the main thread reaches its end of execution, it shuts down all goroutines and ends the program. Since this happens concurrently, it's impossible to say how many strings will be allowed to print.

Comment: +1. Reaching the end of the program guarantees you have written to the channel 5 times. Because channel reads and writes are blocking, this also implies the channel has been read from 5 times. But what is **not** guaranteed is that all 5 of those read values have been concatenated with the "Hello " and "!" strings and `Println`ed before the program exits.